# How to change the culture to another language but keep the currency format in US Dollar?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I use the bellow code to set the cultures that will be available in my Blazor Server side program, but how can I keep the currency always in US dollars after the user changes the language/culture?

```
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
.
.
var app = builder.Build();
.
.
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "es", "pt" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Code used to change it after the user made a selection from the available options:

```
// NavMenu.razor
private void ChangeCulture(string culture)
{
  var uri = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped);
    var query = $"?culture={Uri.EscapeDataString(culture)}&" + $"redirectUri={Uri.EscapeDataString(uri)}";
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Culture/SetCulture" + query, forceLoad: true);
    }
```

Comment: That code doesn’t actually set the culture, does it? What’s in `/Culture/SetCulture`?

Comment: Yes it does. It works perfectly in Blazor server side. I couldn't find this page /Culture/SetCulture. I just copied the code from somewhere and it works.

Comment: My mistake, sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd You were right. That was not the code that actually set the culture. It only changes it. I rewrote my question.